# how to use a kernel patch?

Tags: sound, kernel, codecs, patch

I have a problem with my sound card and there is a patch on git that seem to repair my problem.
[here the patch](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/commit/sound/pci/hda/patch_conexant.c?id=6ffc0898b29a2811a6c0569c5dd9b581980110df)

But I don't know how to use patch. Someone can help me?

edit :I saw that how to [build custom kernel](http://www.carlos-roque.com/2015/05/20/building-and-installing-a-patched-ubuntu-kernel-for-the-surface-pro-3/) but I don't know how to get the patch git adress.

Comment: It is not very straight forward. You will need to build  custom kernels first.

Comment: This patch has been applied to Ubuntu kernels long ago.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the kernel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This patch [has been applied](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/commit/?id=6ffc0898b29a2811a6c0569c5dd9b581980110df) to Ubuntu kernels a year ago.

If you are using a supported Ubuntu kernel, you do not need to apply it again.